# Table that displays differently for different screen sizes with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am working on a website for my softball league, using Bootstrap, and I have a page that displays all of the coaches by team and division with phone numbers and email addresses, and possibly additional information (e.g. an alternate contact or assistant coach).

I want to take advantage of browsers' ability to layout a table and keep columns the same size, so I'm thinking using a `<table>` would be better than using `<div>`s at this point.

To make the table display nicely on different devices, I want to collapse some information together as the screen gets smaller. So this is how the information should look at different sizes:

### Large

```
+------+-------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| Team | Coach | Email | Ph Number 1 | Additional  |
|      |       |       | Ph Number 2 | information |
+------+-------+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

### Medium

```
+------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| Team | Coach | Email       | Additional  |
|      |       | Ph Number 1 | information |
|      |       | Ph Number 2 |             |
+------+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

### Small

```
+-------+-------------+-------------+
| Team  | Email       | Additional  |
| Coach | Ph Number 1 | information |
|       | Ph Number 2 |             |
+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

### Xtra Small

```
+-------------+
| Team        |
| Coach       |
| Email       |
| Ph Number 1 |
| Ph Number 2 |
| Additional  |
| information |
+-------------+
```

I currently have this working in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfren484/rf5am5n8/

The thing I don't like about my solution is that I repeat all of the data in the table 4 times with visible-* and hidden-* classes to show the right ones at each screen size (and show the largest for print media even though the viewport is actually "small").

**My question: Is there a better way to make my table "responsive" without sending 4x the amount of data to the browser?** I could reorganize the table and not repeat the `<tr>` tag four times, but then I'd need more classes on `<td>` tags, so I don't think that would save anything. What I would like would be some other way to collapse it together and only send each piece of data to the client one time.

If there is a good way to do this without any additional library or technology, that would be preferable, but I'd be open to exploring some other plugin that works with Bootstrap to display a table this way.

**TLDR; Is there a way to accomplish (http://jsfiddle.net/jfren484/rf5am5n8/) without repeating my data four times?**

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the solution: [Resposnive Tables](http://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/#).

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #no-more-tables table,
  #no-more-tables thead,
  #no-more-tables tbody,
  #no-more-tables th,
  #no-more-tables td,
  #no-more-tables tr {
    display: block;
  }
  #no-more-tables,
  #no-more-tables table {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  #no-more-tables tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  }
  #no-more-tables td {
    /* Behave  like a "row" */
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1px 8px;
  }
  #no-more-tables td:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="no-more-tables">
  <table class="col-lg-12 table-responsive table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="info">
        <th colspan="5">Fun Division</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="/Team/Foo">Around the Block</a>

        </td>
        <td>Mick Michaelson</td>
        <td>mick.michaelfoo@<span style="display: none;">null</span>yahoo.com</td>
        <td>(999) 555-3412</td>
        <td>Assistant coach Jim Johnson - (999) 555-1111</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="/Team/Foo">Infield Flies</a>

        </td>
        <td>Mick Michaelson</td>
        <td>mick.michaelfoo@<span style="display: none;">null</span>yahoo.com</td>
        <td>(999) 555-3412</td>
        <td>Assistant coach Jim Johnson - (999) 555-1111</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="/Team/Foo">7th Inning Stretchers</a>

        </td>
        <td>Mick Michaelson</td>
        <td>mick.michaelfoo@<span style="display: none;">null</span>yahoo.com</td>
        <td>(999) 555-3412</td>
        <td>Assistant coach Jim Johnson - (999) 555-1111</td>
      </tr>
      <thead>
        <tr class="info">
          <th colspan="5">Games Division</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="/Team/Foo">Hit Squad</a>

        </td>
        <td>Mick Michaelson</td>
        <td>mick.michaelfoo@<span style="display: none;">null</span>yahoo.com</td>
        <td>(999) 555-3412</td>
        <td>Assistant coach Jim Johnson - (999) 555-1111</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="/Team/Foo">Big Sticks</a>

        </td>
        <td>Mick Michaelson</td>
        <td>mick.michaelfoo@<span style="display: none;">null</span>yahoo.com</td>
        <td>(999) 555-3412</td>
        <td>Assistant coach Jim Johnson - (999) 555-1111</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="/Team/Foo">New Car Smell</a>

        </td>
        <td>Mick Michaelson</td>
        <td>mick.michaelfoo@<span style="display: none;">null</span>yahoo.com</td>
        <td>(999) 555-3412</td>
        <td>Assistant coach Jim Johnson - (999) 555-1111</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That's close, but it doesn't combine the data the way I want to do it (moving data into multiple lines in a single cell).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does exactly what you want if you look at the adjusted code.

Comment: I suppose if the headers were removed from the small view size it would be really close to what I have in my mind for the smallest size. Getting it to work for the two intermediate sizes would take some more work, though. I don't think the no-more-tables classes would work on only some of the table cells, though. I seems like this is all or nothing.